# Speed Up Video Processing time FFMPEG while adding multiple images to Video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay multiple images to the video at certain time interval...
but the processing time is too much for a video length of 1 minute.
I used [VideoKit](https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android) Library for it.
Here is my code for adding multiple images to Video.

```
 String[] command = {"-i", inputPath, 
                "-i", imagePath1,"-i", imagePath2,"-i",imagePath3,
                "-filter_complex",
                "[0][1]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,2,10)'[v1];
                 [v1][2]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,20)'[v2];
                 [v2][3]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,20,30)'[v3]",
                "-map", "[v3]",  outputPath};
```

Is there any faster processing library for video processing.

Comment: If you're encoding with libx264 (H.264 video) or libx265 (H.265/HEVC) then use a faster encoding preset (`-preset` option). See FFmpeg Wiki: [H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) or [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

Comment: @llogan As you said i have used "-preset", "ultrafast" commands and it made  processing faster but still i need to work more fluent same as this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newbiz.mvmaster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added two more tags to make processing faster.

```
String[] command = {"-i", inputPath, 
\"-i", imagePath1,"-i", imagePath2,"-i",imagePath3,
"-filter_complex",
"[0][1]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,2,10)'[v1];
[v1][2]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,20)'[v2];
[v2][3]overlay=y=H-h:enable='between(t,20,30)'[v3]",
"-map", "[v3]",
**"-preset", "ultrafast",**  outputPath};
```